# simulating .click() for non http urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, whatsapp

I have taken up a rather ambitious task.

Scenario:

A user gets a **sms** on his mobile. The sms is basically an alert. I want the user to be able to share the message to his whatsapp contacts by clicking on a link rather that he copying the messaging, opening whatsapp, selecting a contact, pasting the message and clicking on send.

If a website has html tag written in the following way:

```
<a id="blood-request-sms" href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">
  B+ required by 21st March at Hyderabad
</a>
```

and the user clicks on the link on a *mobile browser*, whatsapp opens and allows the user to select the contact / group and sends the message (Hello World! in this case)

Since I don't want the user to click more than once till he opens whatsapp to select the contact/group I thought of a design like this:

a) The user gets a sms with a url like goo.gl/qpdRdr

b) This opens a page for which I have written the following code on load of the   page

```
    document.getElementById('blood-request-sms').click();
```

This ideally simulates the click on the `a` element and should open whatsapp. 
This working for any href of http protocol but for whatsapp, this is not happening.

Any way I can get this working??

Thanks,
Lakshman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provided example does actually work on my device (iPhone with iOS 9).

Maybe you could also try to skip the `a`altogether and just assign a new `location.href`:

```
<a id="blood-request-sms" href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">
  B+ required by 21st March at Hyderabad
</a>
<script>
  location.href = "whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!";
</script>
```